# Inserting mysql inside a div inside an array

Tags: html, mysql, arrays, image, slider

I have created a database to access the images inside a slider which uses jquery. The problem starts when I try to insert the connection given that it is an array:

```
<?php
$slides = array(
            '<div data-thumb="images/slider/slides/image1_small.jpg" data-src="images/slider/slides/image1.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Text 1 below image
                </div>
            </div>',
            '<div data-thumb="images/slider/slides/image2_small.jpg" data-src="images/slider/slides/image2.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Text 2 below image
                </div>
            </div>',
            '<div data-thumb="images/slider/slidesimage3_small.jpg" data-src="images/slider/slides/image3.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Text 3 below image
                </div>
            </div>'
);
shuffle($slides);
foreach ($slides as $slides) {
    echo "$slides\n";
}
?>
```

My question is, is there a way to change that array to access the images and the text? I've tried with a while loop but couldn't figure it out.

Update: What I want is to change the array to

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblslider";

if ($result=mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {


     while ($slides = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        '<div data-thumb="images/slider/slides/<? echo $row_DataSlider['strImagesmall'] ?>" data-src="images/slider/slides/<? echo $row_DataSlider['strImage'] ?>">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                <? echo $row_DataSlider['strText'] ?>
            </div>
        </div>'

     }
```

}
        ?>

obviously this is not possible but im looking for a solution to get something like it

Comment: There's nothing to do with MySQL here. What's the problem?

Comment: $slides as $slides is this correct? foreach ($slides as $slide) { echo "$slide\n"; }

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo in your foreach...foreach ($slides as $slides)   (using $slides twice)

I'd put:

```
foreach ($slides as $s) {
    echo $s . "</br>";
}
```